# cordova-plugin-network-information plugin is not triggering onDisconnect() when connected to vpn

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, navigator

I am building a mobile application which works in offline. Offline is checking using cordova-plugin-network-information plugin. The application uses vpn connection hence when wifi connection is turned off onDisconnect() event is not triggering. Is there any possible solution to trigger onDisconnect().

```
this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        this.genericService.setNetworkStatusFlag(false);
        this.toast.presentFailureToast('You are offline.Please try later');
      });

      this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.genericService.setNetworkStatusFlag(true);
         }, 1000);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is this piece of code placed? Make sure it will be in the app.component.ts file, after the platform has loaded.